# How do I include certain conditions in SQL Count

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

```
`CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
  Person_id      NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  Surname        VARCHAR2(20),
  First_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  Sex            CHAR(1),
  Birth_date     DATE,
  Street         VARCHAR2(40),
  Town           CHAR(20),
  Postcode       NUMBER(4),
  Next_of_kin    NUMBER(3)
 );
CREATE TABLE STAFF
(
  Person_id     NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  Start_date    DATE,
  Staff_type    VARCHAR2(15),
  Charges       NUMBER(10,2),
  Resign_date   DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (Person_id) references PERSON(Person_id)
  );
CREATE TABLE WARD (
   Ward_code         CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   Ward_name         VARCHAR2(20),
   Bed_count         NUMBER(4),
   Opened_date       DATE,
   Last_painted_date DATE,
   Daily_charge      NUMBER(10,2)
);
CREATE TABLE OPERATION_TYPE (
   Op_code         CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   Operation_name  VARCHAR2(50),
   Theatre_fee     NUMBER(10,2),
   Days_in         NUMBER(5)
);
CREATE TABLE ADMISSION (
   Admission_id    NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   Patient_id      NUMBER(3),
   Admission_date  DATE NOT NULL,
   Expected_op     CHAR(3),
   Admitted_by     NUMBER(3),
   Ward_code       CHAR(3),
   Discharge_date  DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_id) references PERSON(Person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Expected_op) references OPERATION_TYPE(Op_code),
FOREIGN KEY (Admitted_by) references PERSON(Person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Ward_code) references WARD(Ward_code)
);
CREATE TABLE OPERATION (
   Operation_id     NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   Actual_op        CHAR(3),
   Admission_id     NUMBER(3),
   Op_date          DATE,
   Surgeon          NUMBER(3),
   Anaesthetist     NUMBER(3),
FOREIGN KEY (Surgeon) references PERSON(Person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Anaesthetist) references PERSON(Person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Actual_op) references OPERATION_TYPE(Op_code),
FOREIGN KEY (Admission_id) references ADMISSION(Admission_id)
);
CREATE TABLE OBSERVATION(
   Admission_id  NUMBER(3),
   Observ_date   DATE,
   Observ_time   NUMBER(4),
   Observ_type   CHAR(10),
   Observ_value  NUMBER(4),
   Staff_id      NUMBER(3),
PRIMARY KEY (Admission_id,Observ_date,Observ_time,Observ_type),
FOREIGN KEY (Admission_id) references ADMISSION(Admission_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Staff_id) references STAFF(Person_id)
);
REM***********************
REM  PERSON TABLE
REM***********************
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (101,'Black','Barry','M','31/12/1959','11 High St.','Cooma',2630,102);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (102,'Black','Mary','F','11/04/1965','11 High St.','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (103,'Strathclyde','Albert','M','15/5/1955','3 The Mews','Hawthorne',3171,104);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (104,'Strathclyde','Alice','F','17/7/1955','3 The Mews','Hawthorne',3171,103);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (105,'Green','Gill','F','16/6/1966','124 Main St.','Young',2594,106);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (106,'Green','Graham','M','24/4/1967','124 Main St.','Young',2594,105);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (107,'Gray','Lesley','F','12/9/1972','130 Main St.','Young',2594,109);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (109,'Gray','John','M','14/4/1972','130 Main St.','Young',2594,107);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (110,'Samuelson','Thomas','M','1/1/1964','17 The Mews','Hawthorne',3171,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (111,'Abrahams','Mary','F','15/5/1967','2177A The Esplanade','Ivanhoe',3878,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (112,'Aumann','Monica','F','25/5/1955','29 The Esplanade','Ivanhoe',3878,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (113,'Brown','Melissa','F','8/8/1984','11 East St.','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (114,'Napier','Mary','F','1/1/1971','163 New Rd.','Henty',2658,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (115,'Nelson','Nigel','M','2/2/1972','165 Young Rd.','Temora',2666,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (116,'Newman','Olive','F','3/3/1973','21 Olympic Way','Henty',2658,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (117,'Gray','Lesley','M','31/12/1989','130 Andres St.','Young',2594,105);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (118,'Hon','Tasuku','M','13/3/1953','21 Silcon Height','Henty',2658,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (119,'Livingstone','Frank','M','3/3/2003','21 Sun Height','Henty',2658,122);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (120,'Giggle','Frank','M','23/3/1975','21 Albrige Close','Cooma',2630,121);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (121,'Giggle','Felicia','F','3/3/1980','21 Albrige Close','Cooma',2630,120);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (122,'Black','Frank Jr','M','13/3/2011','21 Stun Height','Henty',2658,123);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (123,'Black','Frances','F','12/12/2005','21 Stun Height','Henty',2658,122);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (124,'Smith','Buddy','M','11/12/1979','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (125,'Smith','Maxime','F','31/12/1979','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,124);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (126,'Smith','Issac','M','1/12/2007','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,124);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (127,'Smith','Ronny','M','3/12/2009','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,124);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (128,'Giggle','Fanny','F','3/12/2007','121 Close Rose','Hillo',2330,120);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (129,'Murad','Nadia','F','3/3/2000','121 Close Rose', 'Hillo',2330,130);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (130,'Murad','Tange','M','3/3/1999','7711 Albrige Close','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (131,'Rome','Paula','F','23/9/1965','21 Height Close','Cooma',2630,132);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (132,'Rome','Paul','M','13/3/1966','21 Height Close','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (133,'Rome','Fay','M','3/3/2017','21 Height Close','Cooma',2630,132);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (134,'Murad','Michelle','F','3/3/2001','1 Height Close','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (135,'Trump','Donald','M','13/3/1956','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (136,'Trump','Melania','F','3/3/1992','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,135);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (137,'Trump','Baron','M','3/6/2005','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,135);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (138,'Johnson','Boris','M','23/9/1965','10 Downing Street','Wagga Wagga',2999,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (139,'Cordeiro','Wayne','M','3/3/1965','777 Hawaii Close Rose', 'Hillo',7770, NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (140,'Cordeiro','Anne','F','23/4/1968','777 Hawaii Close Rose', 'Hillo',7770, 139);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (141,'Thatcher','Margaret','F','21/1/1955','120 Main Sq.','Wagga Wagga',2999,142);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (142,'Thatcher','Denis','M','23/9/1955','120 Main Sq.','Wagga Wagga',2999,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (143,'Thatcher','Carols','F','1/9/1985','120 Main Sq.','Wagga Wagga',2999,142);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (144,'Nelson','Nigel','M','22/2/1992','15 Young Rd.','Temora',2666,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (145,'Neon','Gela','F','2/2/1972','1465 Main Rd.','Temora',2666,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (146,'Twain','Shane','F','21/1/1995','A-129 Main Rose Sq.','Wagga Wagga',2650,147);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (147,'Twain','Dens','M','23/9/1985','A-129 Main Rose Sq.','Wagga Wagga',2650,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (148,'Trump','Ivanka','F','5/3/1985','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,135);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (149,'Trump','Eric','M','3/12/1975','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,135);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (150,'Gates','Bill','M','5/3/1975','2 Rosey Lane','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (151,'Bucket','Eric','M','3/1/1985','11 Oserey Avenue','Cooma',2630,NULL);

REM*******************************************************
REM STAFF TABLE
REM nursing services will not be charged to the patients
REM*******************************************************
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (103,'1/1/2009','Surgeon',4525,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (110,'5/5/2009','Surgeon',5600,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (118,'1/5/2016','Surgeon',7890,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (111,'1/1/2009','Anaesthetist',5900,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (112,'3/3/2009','Anaesthetist',4788,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (114,'1/1/2009','Senior Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (115,'2/2/2016','Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (116,'3/3/2014','Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (125,'23/3/2014','Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (135,'1/1/2019','Senior Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (136,'2/2/2016','Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (138,'23/3/2019','Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (139,'23/3/2020','Senior Nurse',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (150,'1/11/2019','Anaesthetist',6900,NULL);
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (151,'31/1/2019','Anaesthetist',5900,NULL);

REM***********************
REM  WARD TABLE
REM***********************
INSERT INTO WARD VALUES ('C','Covid Bay',90,'31/12/2019',NULL,150.00);
INSERT INTO WARD VALUES ('A','Abraham',80,'1/12/2015','12/05/2011',350.00);
INSERT INTO WARD VALUES ('N','Nightingale',50,'1/12/2017','12/05/2012',450.00);
INSERT INTO WARD VALUES ('F','Flemming',75,'15/11/2009',NULL,230.00);
INSERT INTO WARD VALUES ('L','Lister',80,'1/1/2009','20/12/2013',200.00);
INSERT INTO WARD VALUES ('P','Pasteur',60,'1/12/2009','12/12/2011',250.00);


REM***********************
REM  OPERATION_TYPE TABLE
REM***********************
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('LO','Lobotomy',700.00,10);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('CS','Caesarean',5700.00,3);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('CT','Cataract',670.00,1);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('AP','Appendicectomy',500.00,5);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('HB','Heart Bypass',2000.00,14);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('HT','Heart Transplant',5000.00,30);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('HY','Hysterectomy',800.00,7);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('LA','Leg Amputation',1500.00,10);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('TS','Tonsillectomy',700.00,7);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('LP','Laparoscopy',500.00,1);
INSERT INTO OPERATION_TYPE VALUES ('AR','Arthroscopy ',700.00,17);


REM***********************
REM  ADMISSION TABLE
REM***********************
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (205,101,'2/2/2011','HB',114,'P','21/2/2011');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (275,101,'1/9/2010','HY',115,'L','1/11/2010');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (286,101,'3/5/2016','AR',116,'A','3/7/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (303,101,'3/4/2018','LA',125,'F', '13/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (298,103,'23/1/2016','TS',114,'L','24/04/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (299,103,'23/3/2018','AP',114,'L','23/4/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (305,103,'23/4/2018','HT',125,'F','29/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (321,103,'13/8/2018','AR',125,'F', '23/10/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (283,105,'3/12/2015','AR',116,'A','5/12/2015');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (278,105,'1/1/2011','HB',115,'P','30/1/2011');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (307,105,'3/4/2018','TS',125,'F', '13/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (276,106,'24/8/2010','LA',114,'P','15/9/2010');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (287,106,'3/5/2016','TS',114,'A','3/6/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (274,109,'1/9/2019','AP',114,'P','9/9/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (288,109,'23/5/2016','LO',114,'F','3/07/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (301,112,'13/4/2018','AP',125,'F','16/4/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (304,112,'23/4/2019','LO',114,'L','23/5/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (279,113,'3/9/2010','TS',115,'F','10/9/2010');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (284,113,'3/12/2015','HY',116,'A','03/01/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (285,113,'3/5/2016','HT',116,'A','3/6/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (300,113,'23/4/2018','AR',114,'L','25/6/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (306,113,'13/8/2018','AP',125,'L', '13/9/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (277,114,'20/9/2010','AP',115,'P','30/9/2010');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (289,115,'11/4/2016','LO',114,'L','3/6/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (290,115,'5/7/2016','TS',114,'L','3/09/2016');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (308,115,'23/3/2018','AR',114,'L','25/3/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (280,117,'13/9/2010','AP',115,'F','25/9/2010');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (281,117,'3/9/2014','HB',116,'A','21/9/2014');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (282,117,'3/12/2015','LA',116,'A','14/12/2015');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (309,126,'23/3/2018','TS',125,'L', '13/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (310,127,'13/5/2018','AP',125,'L', '28/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (311,124,'3/5/2018','LO',125,'A', '23/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (312,127,'21/6/2019','LO',125,'L','22/8/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (313,124,'22/6/2019','AP',125,'A','22/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (314,109,'21/6/2019','LO',125,'L','22/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (315,126,'12/6/2019','AP',125,'A','22/9/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (316,114,'22/7/2019','HB',125,'A','12/12/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (318,128,'3/5/2019','LA',116,'A','4/6/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (319,129,'23/3/2019','TS',125,'L', '13/4/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (320,130,'3/5/2019','LA',116,'F','4/6/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (328,119,'3/3/2019','TS',115,'N', '3/4/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (322,132,'3/5/2019','LA',116,'A','4/6/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (323,133,'23/3/2019','TS',125,'L', '13/4/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (324,131,'3/5/2018','LA',116,'F','4/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (325,118,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (326,102,'3/5/2018','LA',116,'F','4/5/2018');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (327,104,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (339,107,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (329,110,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (330,111,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (331,116,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (332,121,'21/6/2019','TS',125,'L','22/7/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (333,123,'22/7/2019','AP',125,'A','22/9/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (334,134,'21/8/2019','AP',115,'L','22/12/2019');
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (335,128,'12/8/2020','AP',115,'A',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (336,125,'22/7/2020','HB',115,'A',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (337,120,'21/8/2020','AP',116,'L',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (338,130,'22/7/2020','AP',125,'N',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (340,131,'22/8/2020','AP',125,'N',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (341,122,'22/8/2020','AP',125,'N',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (490,139,'11/8/2020','AP',125,'F',NULL);
INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (491,140,'7/9/2020','AP',138,'F',NULL);
 

REM***********************
REM  OPERATION TABLE
REM***********************
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (317,'HB',205,'4/2/2011',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (355,'LA',276,'25/8/2010',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (363,'AP',276,'3/9/2010',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (360,'AP',277,'22/9/2010',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (361,'AP',274,'2/9/2010',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (362,'HT',275,'3/9/2010',110,112);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (364,'AP',279,'3/9/2010',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (365,'AP',280,'6/9/2010',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (366,'HB',281,'6/9/2014',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (367,'HY',284,'6/12/2015',103,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (368,'LO',285,'6/5/2016',118,112);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (369,'AP',286,'6/5/2016',118,112);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (370,'TS',287,'7/5/2016',118,112);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (371,'LA',288,'26/5/2016',110,111); 
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (372,'LO',289,'16/4/2016',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (373,'TS',290,'6/5/2016',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (381,'TS',298,'26/2/2016',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (382,'AP',299,'26/3/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (383,'TS',300,'26/5/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (384,'TS',309,'16/4/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (385,'LO',309,'26/3/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (386,'AP',310,'18/5/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (387,'AP',311,'4/5/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (388,'LO',311,'11/5/2018',110,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (389,'AP',315,'13/6/2019',118,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (390,'HB',316,'23/7/2019',118,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (391,'LO',312,'22/6/2019',118,111);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (392,'HT',341,'28/8/2019',118,112);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (393,'HT',340,'27/8/2019',118,112);
INSERT INTO OPERATION VALUES (394,'LO',491,'26/4/2020',103,112);


REM***********************
REM  OBSERVATION TABLE
REM***********************
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (205,'2/2/2011',1500,'Temp',38,114);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (274,'4/9/2010',0601,'Temp',39,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (275,'1/9/2010',1400,'Pulse',64,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (275,'1/9/2010',1400,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (275,'3/9/2010',1800,'Temp',40,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (275,'3/9/2010',2200,'Temp',40,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (275,'4/9/2010',0610,'Pulse',82,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (275,'4/9/2010',0610,'Temp',38,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (277,'24/9/2010',0600,'Temp',39,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (284,'5/12/2015',0600,'Temp',39,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (284,'5/12/2015',0600,'Pulse',89,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (284,'6/12/2015',0600,'Temp',37,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (284,'6/12/2015',0600,'Pulse',87,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (285,'7/5/2016',0600,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (285,'8/5/2016',0600,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (285,'8/5/2016',0600,'Pulse',82,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (285,'9/5/2016',0600,'Temp',37,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (286,'7/5/2016',0600,'Temp',39,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (286,'8/5/2016',0600,'Temp',33,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (286,'8/5/2016',0600,'Pulse',86,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (286,'9/5/2016',0600,'Temp',36,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (287,'7/5/2016',0600,'Temp',35,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (287,'8/5/2016',0600,'Temp',37,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (287,'8/5/2016',0600,'Pulse',82,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (287,'9/5/2016',0600,'Temp',37,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (289,'19/5/2016',0600,'Temp',39,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (289,'20/5/2016',1400,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (289,'22/5/2016',0800,'Temp',37,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (289,'26/5/2016',0700,'Temp',37,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (289,'29/5/2016',0700,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (300,'23/4/2018',1400,'Pulse',74,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (300,'23/4/2018',1400,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (300,'23/4/2018',1800,'Temp',30,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (300,'23/4/2018',2200,'Temp',40,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (300,'24/4/2018',0610,'Pulse',82,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (300,'24/4/2018',0610,'Temp',38,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (303,'13/4/2018',1400,'Pulse',64,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (303,'13/4/2018',1400,'Temp',38,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (303,'13/4/2018',1800,'Temp',30,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (303,'23/4/2018',2200,'Temp',40,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (303,'23/4/2018',0610,'Pulse',82,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (303,'23/4/2018',0610,'Temp',38,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'3/5/2018',1400,'Pulse',54,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'4/5/2018',1400,'Temp',38,115);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'3/5/2018',1800,'Temp',40,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'4/5/2018',2200,'Temp',41,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'4/5/2018',1800,'Temp',39,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'5/5/2018',0610,'Pulse',72,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (311,'5/5/2018',0610,'Temp',38,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (310,'13/5/2018',1400,'Pulse',84,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (310,'13/5/2018',1400,'Temp',28,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (310,'14/5/2018',1800,'Temp',60,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (310,'15/5/2018',2200,'Temp',40,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (310,'16/5/2018',0610,'Pulse',92,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (310,'16/5/2018',0610,'Temp',35,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (341,'22/8/2019',0610,'Temp',39,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'25/8/2019',0610,'Temp',39,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'25/8/2019',0610,'Pulse',75,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'26/8/2019',0610,'Temp',37,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'26/8/2019',0610,'Pulse',70,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'27/8/2019',0610,'Pulse',68,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'27/8/2019',0610,'Temp',37,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (340,'29/8/2019',0610,'Pulse',73,116);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (490,'17/4/2020',0600,'Temp',38,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (490,'18/4/2020',0600,'Temp',37,125);
INSERT INTO OBSERVATION VALUES (490,'19/4/2020',0600,'Temp',38,125);
```

select town, c.count(2021- to_char(birth_date,'YYYY'))*100/count(*) as "Population"
from person, person c
group by town

Using Apex Oracle here, I need to set a condition for c.count where it only takes into account >60, but whenever I put the condition in, errors pop up, would greatly appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Explain what you want to calculate.  A Cartesian Product on the same table is suspicious.

Comment: I've adjusted the post above to include the table I am using. Basically what I am trying to do is from the person table, only get those above 60, convert it to percentage, and sort by the city they are in.

Comment: You swung too far the other way with the sample data.  You need as little as possible to get the problem across.   In your case, only the sql for the person table, and only a handful of rows. And then a simple text table of the desired results.

Comment: Ahh I see, I rarely use Stack but I'll definitely take note of that, thanks for the help!

Comment: Of course.  Let me know if my answer (below) is helpful.  If so, consider accepting it.  If not, mention why in the comments to that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't really need a cross join of 'person' with 'person'.  So I'm dropping that logic from the sources.

I don't have and Oracle instance to work with, but I believe the code below, which uses a case statement to achieve your conditional need, should work for you:

```
select       town, 
             c.count(
                 case when ap.age > 60 then ap.age end
             ) 100 / count() as "Population" 
from         person 
cross apply  (select age = 2021 - to_char(birth_date,'YYYY')) ap
group by     town
```